# Perl hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash-of-hashes

I have a file with a list of lines like

at 12345 injected value 1 to 'signal_A'
at 12345 injected value 0 to 'signal_B'
at 12346 injected value 1 to 'signal_A'
at 12348 injected value 1 to 'signal_A'
at 12350 injected value 0 to 'signal_A'
at 12354 injected value 0 to 'signal_A'

From this file, I want to read till the end of the file and  I want to build a hash of hashes something like

```
%tab = (
       12345 => {           
       signal => "signal_A",           
       value  => "1",        
     },

      12345 => {
       signal => "signal_B",
       value  => "1",
     },
);
```

Also I want to iterate this hash table.

Will highly appreciate your help.

Comment: [`perldoc perdsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 4):

You have two elements with the same key. That data structure cannot exist. How about the following instead:

```
%tab = (
   12345 => [
      {
         signal => "signal_A",           
         value  => "1",        
      },

      {
         signal => "signal_B",
         value  => "1",
      },
   ],
   12346 => [
      {
         signal => "signal_A",           
         value  => "1",        
      },
   ],
   ...
);
```

You'd use the following to created it

```
push @{ $tab{$id} }, { signal => $signal, value => $value };
```

You can iterate over the structure using

```
for my $id (keys %tab) {
   for $event (@{ $tab{$id} }) {
      ...$event->{signal}...;
      ...$event->{value}...;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi ikegami,  Sorry about the typo,  that exactly fits my need :)  Can you please tell me how can I print the hash table?

Comment: Good catch about double key. Seems toplevel hash must be replaced with array since 12345 is a pid/timestamp/line number

Comment: Hi , I tried this and worked as well.                                         
foreach $key (sort keys %tab) {           

    my $tsig   = $tab{$key}{Sig};
    my $tval   = $tab{$key}{Val};  
    print "The val at $key  $tsig, $tval \n";

   }